# Modify an array with setState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an JSON array:

[image: 1]

```
function createData(nom, age, poids, ) {
  return {
    nom,
    age,
    poids,

  };
}

const [count, setCount] = useState([
  ]);
  
  
  setCount(count=>count.concat(createData("mathieu",15)))
  setCount(count=>count.concat(createData("jean",25)))
  setCount(count=>count.concat(createData("ginette",55)))




  setCount(count=>count[0].poids=13) // doesn't work
```

I'm trying to add poids=13 in a existing json array when nom= mathieu but doesn't work.
Can you help me, I'm new on react hooks.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify "doesn't work"? That could mean anything. You get an error? Unexpected output?

Answer (score 2):

Your `setCount()` callback should return the *new value* of the state. `count[0].poids = 13` will return `13`. You should also [not modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly), although your using `setState`, you're retrieving the previous state and trying to update it directly.

Instead, you can use `.map()` to return a new array of objects, which will be your new state. Within the `.map()` callback you can specify how each of your objects "transforms"/changes. If the `nom` is "mathieu" you can return a newly transformed object, otherwise, you can simply just return the current object.

```
setCount(count => count.map(
  obj => obj.nom === "mathieu" ? {...obj, poids: 13} : obj
));
```

Comment: only add a parameter to be more generic, (count,name), `obj.nom === name` ...